# on dcast() argument "value.var"

Tags: r, rstudio, reshape, reshape2, dcast

So, I used dcast() on a dataframe last time in which one column was ID and the other multiple codes assigned per id. My df1 looked like this:

```
ID  codes    gfreq
123  FGV34     0.988
123  FGV34     0.988
123  FGV34     0.988 
566  WER45     na
566  FGV34      0.988
566  FGV34      0.988
```

in order to manipulate the above format into :

```
ID  FGV34  WER45
123  1       0
566  1       1

dcast(df1, ID ~ codes)
```

And it had worked perfectly. 
Now, i have a similar dataframe df2, which has just TWO columns, ID and codes.

```
ID  codes    
123  FGV34     
123  FGV34    
123  FGV34     
566  WER45     
566  FGV34      
566  FGV34
```

When I run it into dcast:
1. I get a warning about Value.var being overridden and codes column is used as value.var which is okay
2. The format in which I am getting the output is completely different this time.

```
ID  FGV34  WER45
123 FGV34    NA
566 FGV34  WER45
```

I have checked the datatypes of the attributes in df1 and df2. They are the same for both ID and codes.
I want help in getting the output like before with either 0 or 1 instead of NA and column name.
Secondly, I want to understand what changed for the dcast() to be behaving differently.

Comment: A `tidr` and `dplyr` solution might help. Try this `df %>%
filter(!is.na(Codes)) %>%  
  spread(Codes, ID)`

Comment: No, I think it requires for the columns to not have any repetitive values.. But in my case ID repeats..

Comment: Do you have your data frame, I just tested with a repeat and it works.

Comment: No luck. The following is the error that I'm getting.. "Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 61 rows:"

Comment: Likely you have repeat in the `Codes`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized. There are repeats in both columns.. is there any modification of the same logic that can be used with repeats in both? I still wonder why dcast would work once and not now..

Comment: It creates a sparse with `NA`, using  unique column. See my update if it helps.

Comment: @deepseefan So, I tried the update. It works but unfortunately, I need the ID column to be intact and binary entry for every code that it contains.

Comment: See if the `data.table` solution below helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `reshape2` and `spread` have been deprecated or retired - the `tidyverse` now wants you to use `pivot_wider`. I'm not up to date on that syntax, but `dcast` still does what you want it to with `data.table`.

```r
library(data.table)
d1 <- data.table(ID = c(11,11,11,12,12,12), 
                 codes = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), 
                 gfreq = c(.5,.5,.5,NA,.5,.5))
dcast(d1, ID ~ codes)
#> Using 'gfreq' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#> Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#>    ID a b
#> 1: 11 3 0
#> 2: 12 2 1

d2 <- data.table(ID = c(11,11,11,12,12,12), 
                 codes = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'))
dcast(d2, ID ~ codes)
#> Using 'codes' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#> Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#>    ID a b
#> 1: 11 3 0
#> 2: 12 2 1

## If you only want 1's and 0's
dcast(unique(d2), ID ~ codes, 
      fun.aggregate = length)
#> Using 'codes' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#>    ID a b
#> 1: 11 1 0
#> 2: 12 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This gave me the output I was looking for.  Thank you. So, from what I understand, having a unique column in the dataframe is not a prerequisite for dcast() to recognize the input rows?

Comment: Your data frame is now `unique(d2)`. The combination is unique. I think.

Comment: Correct. `dcast` uses an aggregation function (which generally defaults to length) - so it can reduce multiple values to just one. When it is `length` it's essentially counting each combination of `ID` and `codes`.

Comment: @deepseefan, `dcast` is used in all 3 examples. You do not need unique rows for it - it uses an aggregation function (`length` in all 3 cases above). The `unique` call in the last example simply counts each combination exactly once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200956/discussion-between-clancystats-and-deepseefan).